# Is password recovery link more secure than plain-text password transfer when considering man-in-the-middle attacks?

Tags: security, password-recovery

Considering [this paper](http://www.fishnetsecurity.com/6labs/resource-library/white-paper/best-practices-secure-forgot-password-feature) and simple common sense: why is latter more vulnerable than former?

I mean, if we have eavesdropping situation than what is difference between two scenarios:

- Plain-text: hacker requests password recovery, catches the password, gains access to the account
- Recovery link: hacker requests password recovery, catches the link, uses it, gains access to the account

I know that we mustn't store the password as plain-text at all, but lets assume that we have no control over this part — is there any difference in this case?

Comment: I've attempted to make your question title a little more specific, to mirror your description. If that was incorrect, please feel free to change it again. =)

Comment: Also, I must say, this subject is rather broad. You have to take into account how your users will feel about being sent their passwords in plain-text, as well as *other* security factors. Just because it *might* be equally secure in *this* case, doesn't mean this is the only attack that will try to gain access to the system. =)

Answer (score 2):

The following benefits are present:

1. users feel safer when they don't receive passwords in plaintext (even when they are kept so on the server)
2. single-use link ensures that the user changes the password (and maybe cares to put it down somewhere or use some password that can be remembered)
3. The last but maybe the most important - with the link approach the hacker would have to change the password and the user can detect that his account has been broken by seeing that he can't login anymore.